# How to add a custom marker in Android systrace?

Tags: android, performance, systrace

I am using systrace to dig into the performance issue in my app, I am wondering if there's a way to add a tag / marker when certain event happens in the systrace result? The specific event I am looking for is input event, but it's hard to tell from systrace which input event is which. I am on Android 4.2.2

Cheers,

Johnny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, using [android.os.Trace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Trace.html), but the feature wasn't added until Android 4.3 (API 18).  You can find an example [here](http://bigflake.com/systrace/).